# In Scala futures, should I make my functions return a Future or return a Try?

Tags: scala

When I use Scala futures I feel confused as to whether I should return a future or return a Try. Since my code could fail, so I expect to return a Try which may have success or failure and the user of the function could use the function to create a future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Future`s can fail, yes, but that failure is self-contained--it's not going to propagate to the rest of your code. `Future` is very similar to `Try` in that sense, and in fact the value it holds is `Option[Try[T]]`.

So when you `map` a `Future`, you'll only be handling the `Success` case of it's `value`, and if you want to handle the failures, you can use `recover` or `recoverTo`.

`Future` callback functions also deal with the `Try` directly:

```
 Future(...).onComplete {
     case Success(value) => ...
     case Failure(throwable) =>
 }
```

Stick with `Future` when you need async results, as it uses `Try` internally anyway.

Comment: So just return def something() = future { } always since it has Try inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your result asynchronously you should use `Future`. `Future` has 2 types of results: `Success` and `Failure` which as you know are descendants of Try, so in any case you'll catch the failre if it happens.

Comment: "which as you know are descendants of Try": err, What?

Comment: see answer of LimbSoup

Comment: Forget it, I somehow thought you were saying that `Future` is a "descendant" of `Try`. I may need some more sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I was designing yet another actor API. What should I use for result type of send? If I want clients of my code to return back to it's business as far as it possible (in other words, fire-and-forget type of sending) and process response somewhere in the future I would go with the `Future`. If I want to block until response will come back I will pick `Try`.

Hope, that makes things a bit clear for you.